# How to setup checkBox value on yii

Tags: yii

My DB column name **subscribed** tinyint(1),

I want if checkBox is checked then value send 1 if not checked then value send 0.

This is my code-

```
<?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'subscribed'); ?>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'subscribed',array('value' => '1', 'uncheckValue'=>'0')); ?>
```

Here, value for checked checkbox is `1` and unchecked checkbox is `0`

Answer (score 2):

In your view file:

```
<?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'attribute'); ?> //in your case 'attribute' is 'subscribed'
```

in your controller

```
<?php
//if checked, return 1;
//if unchecked, return 0;
.........
$checkbox_value=$model->attribute; //in your case 'attribute' is 'subscribed'
echo $checkbox_value;
.......
?>
```